# Computing a field extension by hand

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, alternative-proof

Let $k$ be a field, and $K=k(t)$ be the field of rational functions (where $t$ is indeterminate). Let $F=k(t^2)$. A typical element of $F$ will look like:
$$
\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{2i} t^{2i}}{\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{m} b_{2i} t^{2i}} \ \ \ \textrm{where } a_{2i}, b_{2i}\in k
$$
It is a fact that $F\subseteq K$ is a field extension of degree $2$, where $\{1, t\}$ is a basis of $K$ over $F$.

I 'understand' the proof of this fact (which seems to rely on the fact that $g(x)=x^2-t^2 \in F[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $t\in K$ over $F$). But I am interested in how to explicitly write elements of $K$ in the basis $\{1, t\}$. For example, how would you write 
$$
\frac{1}{t^5+t^4+4t^3+7t^2+3}
$$
as $b_{1} t + b_{0}$ where $b_{0}, b_{1}\in F$? I have reduced this problem to the following:

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ over some field. Then there exists another polynomial $g(x)$ (over the same field) such that
>   $f(x) g(x)$ has no terms $x^{m}$ with $m$ odd.

How would I go about proving this (if it is true..)?

Comment: First expand the element in series (Long division could to it). Then gather all odd powers and all even powers. The sum of the even powers is an element of $F$ times $1$, and the sum of the odd powers is $t$ times an element of $F$.

Comment: Another way (equivalent) is to take the given element $f(t)$ and look at $f(t)=\frac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}\cdot 1+\frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{2t}\cdot t$. Notice that $\frac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}$ and $\frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{2t}$ are in $F$.

Comment: @ABC: For your first comment, I understand how to gather the terms for polynomials… How to do it for rational functions? Edit: Oh expansion in series… like infinite series.

Comment: @ABC: Ah second comment is very nice. Thank you :)

Comment: The first comment is talking about the series expansion of the rational function. Both comments are doing the same. The second is faster.

Comment: @ABC: Oh I see (I don't have much experience with expanding rational functions in series, other than geometric series $1/(1-x)$ :)). What do you think about the statement in block quotes?

Comment: Do this. Assume that $f(x)=\prod(x-r_i)$ in some splitting field. Put $g(x):=\prod (x+r_i)=(-1)^{\text{deg}(f)}f(-x)$. Then $f(x)g(x)=\prod(x^2-r_i^2)$, which will have only even powers.

Comment: @ABC: That's almost ridiculous :P (this is a compliment!) Please post it as an answer.

Comment: If you wish. But it is pretty much the same here or there.

Comment: @ABC: That's true. But I want to upvote and accept your answer as a form of gratitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If $f\in K$ then $$f(t)=\frac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}\cdot1+\frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{2t}\cdot t,$$
   where $\frac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}$ and $\frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{2t}$ are elements of $F$ because they are both even polynomials.
2. If $f(x)$ is given then we can take $g(x):=(-1)^{\text{deg}(f)}f(-x)$. We will have $f(x)g(x)=(-1)^{\text{deg}(f)}f(x)f(-x)$, which is even, and therefore has only even powers.